# Are there dragon stats in any published OWOD or NWOD books?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, dragons

I play in a World of Darkness game, and I have seen two different powers that allow someone turn into mythic creatures, such as dragons. I have never found stats on a dragon though in any WOD books. Does anyone know if WOD has a published book, that contains stats for a dragon?

Comment: Hi Butter Finkle, welcome to the site. By convention, tags only describe the content of the question, and since you've asked for all OWOD and NWOD content, those two tags will cover everything fine. It might be _for_ a LARP, but that's inconsequential for the question itself, unless that LARP also doubles as a rules source you're interested in - in which case, ask for that too! (The exception to this on RPG.SE is when we're using tags to specify the system we're asking about for context, and don't otherwise mention the system in the question.)

Comment: I don't have access to the books now, but I know that some of the Mage and Changeling books have stats for dragons. I'll try to dig them up tonight.

Comment: Comment not answer, since it isn't nWoD: _Dark Ages Mage_ stats out the "Sin Dragons" - one for each of the seven deadly sins.

Comment: @doppelgreener Actually, usually LARP uses Mind Eye Theatre rules, which differ from tabletop system. So, the distinction could be useful.

Comment: @BrianS How Dark Ages: Mage isn't World of Darkness?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Bygone Bestiary, for Mage: The Crusade, Mage: The Ascension, Changeling: The Dreaming and Vampire: Dark Ages has stats for Dragons and other mythical beasts.

As @BrianS found, Dark Ages: Mage contains stats for several types of Dragons, including some weird ones incarnating the deadly sins.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is coming. Descriptions of **Beast: the Primordial,** the nWoD game due in 2015, suggest that it will be trivial to play a dragon in that — the Integrity replacement is Hunger, Lair is the name of your secret space, and your adversaries are Heroes come to hunt you. So, if you can hold out for another year, you'll have all you'll need.

As a stopgap, one of the kiths of the Fairest seeming in **Changeling: the Lost** is "Draconic." You won't be an enormous lizard, but it's a start.

Comment: there is a dragon true fey statted in autumn nightmares. But i was never sure if it was a metaphor or not. With the True Fey it probably doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

Oh, and don't forget Mokole (the werereptiles) that can have dragon-like form. [Here is unnoficial list of changes](http://wolfshaderp.wikidot.com/form-stats#toc6) [and here is the official one](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Archid)for their Archid form with stats Strength +4, Dexterity –1, Stamina +4, Manipulation –3, Appearance 0 (causes Delirium). To make them dragon-like you'd need: Fire Breath, Dragon Mask and I'd say Multiple Limbs+ Wings. If you want to actually fly you need Hollow Bones otherwise get Huge Size and Armor.

Note: for most shapeshifters (including even Mokole themselves) dragon = Wyrm